# Vertically align numbers in siunitx column at the bottom

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, siunitx, makecell

I have a table with different row sizes and some `S[]` columns from package siunitx. By default, the numbers in the S columns are vertically centered in each row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.3]S[table-format=7.1]}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Program} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Time [s]}    &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Memory [kB]} \\

    \makecell[l]{
    some\\
    multiline\\
    code}   &
    10.0021 &
    61.4    \\

    \makecell[l]{
    more\\
    code}   &
    0.407   &
    11782   \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to align the numbers in the S columns at the bottom of the row instead. How can I do that? I heard of the `b{}` column, but this seems not be compatible with the horizontal number alignment from siunitx (in addition, I would prefer to not explicitly provide the width for the columns manually). I did not find any hint in the siunitx documentation on how that is possible.

Does someone know a convenient solution for that, maybe by extending the siunitx package? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `S` columns align like `c` or `l` columns on the text baseline, it is your makecell in column 1 that is vertically centred you want to top align it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`S` columns align like `c` or `l` columns on the text baseline, it is your `\makecell` in column 1 that is vertically centred you want to top or bottom align it.

Comment: Ah, seems like I missed some of the basics. So I just needed to change `\makecell[l]` to `\makecell[bl]`. Thanks!